# Subroutines in BASIC

Tags: string, variables, call, subroutine, basic

I'm following this code from a book about programming in Liberty BASIC:

```
NOMAINWIN
PROMPT "Your name"; name$
CALL DisplayMessage name$
END

SUB DisplayMessage stuff$
X = INT(RND(1) * 2) + 1
IF X = 1 THEN
NOTICE stuff$ + " is a nice person."
ELSE
NOTICE stuff$ + " is a terrible person."
END IF
END SUB
```

and wondering why wouldn't you just use `name$` in the subroutine instead of `stuff$`? And how does the subroutine know to make the connection between `name$` and `stuff$`?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions in reverse order: `CALL DisplayMessage name$` says to execute the subroutine `DisplayMessage` with the current value of `name$` put into `stuff$`.  This mechanism allows `DisplayMessage` to be used to print things other than `name$`, making the subroutine much more useful.

Comment: Thanks for that Scott. Also, if I had 2 or more variables, for example:

`NOMAINWIN`
`PROMPT "Your name"; name$`
`PROMPT "Your age"; age$`
`CALL DisplayMessage name$, age$`
`END`
`SUB DisplayMessage stuff$, thing$`
`X = INT(RND(1) * 2) + 1`
`IF X = 1 THEN`
`NOTICE stuff$ + " is a nice person."`
`ELSE`
`NOTICE thing$ + " is a good age."`
`END IF`
`END SUB`

this code would assign `name$` to `stuff$` and `age$` to `thing$` because that's the order in which they're listed in the parameter lists?